# two charts in one image using pchart

Tags: sample, pchart

I'm struggling to generate two charts in same image. The problem that I have at this moment is that when I'm using my approach, i get some bad results. As you can see from the output picture, I get two vertical axes on the first chart. I need two vertical axes only on the second chart.

I assume that my code is bad, or my approach is bad. How do you generate two charts into the same image with pcharts. This problem arrives only when I need two vertical axes and multiple charts on same image.

[image]

and my code:

```
<?php   
 include("../pchart/class/pData.class.php");
 include("../pchart/class/pDraw.class.php");
 include("../pchart/class/pImage.class.php");

 $MyData = new pData();  
 $MyData->addPoints(array(-4,VOID,VOID,12,8,3),"probe1");
 $MyData->addPoints(array(3,12,15,8,5,-5),"probe2");
 $MyData->addPoints(array(2,7,5,18,19,22),"probe3");
 $MyData->addPoints(array(14,12,10,8,9,12),"probe4");
 $MyData->addPoints(array(3,4,5,7,6,4),"probe5");


 $MyData->setAxisName(0,"Temperatures");
 $MyData->addPoints(array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"),"Labels");
 $MyData->setSerieDescription("Labels","Months");
 $MyData->setAbscissa("Labels");

 $MyData->setSerieOnAxis("probe4", 1);
 $MyData->setAxisPosition(1,AXIS_POSITION_RIGHT);

 $MyData->setSerieDrawable (array("probe4", "probe5"), FALSE);


 $myPicture = new pImage(700,400,$MyData);
 $myPicture->drawRectangle(0,0,699,399,array("R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0));


 $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"../pchart/fonts/Forgotte.ttf","FontSize"=>11));
 $myPicture->drawText(250,55,"Average temperature",array("FontSize"=>20,"Align"=>TEXT_ALIGN_BOTTOMMIDDLE));

 $myPicture->setGraphArea(60,60,670,190);
 $myPicture->drawFilledRectangle(60,60,670,190,array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255,"Surrounding"=>-200,"Alpha"=>10));
 $myPicture->drawScale(array("DrawSubTicks"=>TRUE));
 $myPicture->drawLineChart(array("DisplayValues"=>TRUE,"DisplayColor"=>DISPLAY_AUTO));

 $MyData->setSerieDrawable (array("probe1", "probe2", "probe3"), FALSE);
 $MyData->setSerieDrawable (array("probe4", "probe5"), TRUE);


 $myPicture->setGraphArea(60,240,670,370);
 $myPicture->drawFilledRectangle(60,240,670,370,array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255,"Surrounding"=>-200,"Alpha"=>10));
 $myPicture->drawScale(array("DrawSubTicks"=>TRUE));
 $myPicture->drawLineChart(array("DisplayValues"=>TRUE,"DisplayColor"=>DISPLAY_AUTO));


 $myPicture->stroke();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better approach, but I don't know how to use it in my case. I don't need pie charts, and pImage class supports only dimensions as the first params.

```
$MyData->addPoints($AAA,"AAA");
$MyData->addPoints($abscisse,"Labels");

$myPicture = new pImage(X,Y,$MyData);
.....
$MyData->setSerieDrawable("AAA",TRUE);
$myPicture->drawBarChart();

$MyData2->addPoints($BBB,"BBB")
$PieChart = new pPie($myPicture,$MyData2);
$PieChart->draw3DPie(X,Y,....);

....

$myPicture->stroke();
```